# Catch all the post events events after be exceucted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have more than 100 events request in my project.
But basically, all those request return the same format in a json.

```
{status: 200, message: "the message", id: 50}
```

or

```
{status: 500, message: "the message", id: 50}
```

And messages similar to those, but exist a way to catch all the post events when the excecution finished to show a message? 
I'm trying build a generic receptor for all the request. It is possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you might try using the [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) promise library

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'events' or 'requests' here.  Do you mean AJAX requests to your server with method=POST?  If so, jQuery's ajaxComplete() function may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (a, b) {
        //console.log(this);
        var x = a;
        var y = b;
        this.addEventListener('load', function () {
            //console.log(this);
            var z = JSON.parse(this.response);
            //Here you can filter all the request results
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```